# AVAudioEngine no sound

Tags: swift, iphone, avfoundation

I have been trying for a while now how to stream real time audio from Data provided from a URLSessionDataTask in iOS.

I have declared a custom class for managing the player actions and it looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class AudioDataPlayer: NSObject {

    //MARK:- Variables
    //MARK: Constants
    enum Status{
        case playing
        case notPlaying
    }

    let audioPlayerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioPlayerQueue", qos: DispatchQoS.userInteractive)


    //MARK: Vars
    private (set) var currentStatus:Status = .notPlaying

    private var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private var streamingAudioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    private (set) var streamingAudioFormat: AVAudioFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 48000, channels: 2, interleaved: false)!



    //MARK:- Constructor
    override init() {
        super.init()

    }



    //MARK:- Private methods



    //MARK:- Public methods
    func processData(_ data:Data) throws{

        if currentStatus == .notPlaying{

            do{

                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default, options: [.allowAirPlay])
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    try audioEngine.enableManualRenderingMode(.realtime, format: streamingAudioFormat, maximumFrameCount: 3072)
                }

                audioEngine.attach(streamingAudioPlayerNode)
                audioEngine.connect(streamingAudioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: streamingAudioFormat)

                currentStatus = .playing

            }
            catch{

                print("\(logClassName) ERROR -> \(error.localizedDescription)")

            }

        }

        audioPlayerQueue.async {

            if let audioPCMBuffer = data.makePCMBuffer(format: self.streamingAudioFormat){

                self.streamingAudioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioPCMBuffer, completionHandler: {

                   //TODO
                })

                if !self.audioEngine.isRunning{

                    try! self.audioEngine.start()
                    self.streamingAudioPlayerNode.play()

                }

            }
            else{

                print("\(self.logClassName) TEST -> Ignoring data to play ...")

            }

        }

    }

    func stop(){

        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.detach(streamingAudioPlayerNode)
        currentStatus = .notPlaying

    }


}
```

The function that manages the incoming data is 'processData(_ data:Data)' and it is called like this from another class:

```
let processingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "processingQueue", qos: DispatchQoS.userInteractive)

var audioDataPlayer:AudioDataPlayer = AudioDataPlayer()

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {

    processingQueue.async {

        try! self.audioDataPlayer.processData(data)

    }

}
```

I have got the code from forums and the apple documanetation website. However, maybe I still quite don't understand how it works and there is no sound comming from the device...

The audio data is 48K, 16bit and 2 channels format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your audio data is 16bit (integer, one would assume), you need to initialize the `AVAudioFormat` with `pcmFormatInt16` instead of `pcmFormatFloat32`.

And being non interleaved seems a bit odd for this format, so you may have to set `interleaved` to `true`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and I get the following error --> 019-02-14 08:10:46.177160+0000 MyAppl[307:10016] AUBase.cpp:832:DispatchSetProperty:  ca_require: ValidFormat(inScope, inElement, newDesc) InvalidFormat

Comment: the error occurs when I connect the streamingAudioPlayerNode

Comment: Are you actually sure you're getting raw, uncompressed audio samples without any header information etc. from the url session? So it's not an mp3 or another file format?

Comment: I think so because I am capable to to write the data into a file using AudioFileWriteBytes. Worth saying that the data comes in different array sizes.

Comment: can it be something with the size of data scheduled?

Comment: @ReimondHill did you manage to fix the `ValidFormat` error? Having the same issue.

Comment: No, I haven't. Sorry